# Scatterplot and Spearmans rho not matching

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataset with non-parametric data where I'm looking for correlation between two observations. When I run spearmans correlation test i get the following answer in R:

```
Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  g120 and landscape1000
S = 990.93, p-value = 0.5936
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.1307591
```

As you can se the rho is positive but the output I get from my script is not: [image]

The code for plotting the figure is:

```
    # 1km - Gradering 1, 20m Scatter plot and correlation with spearman test



plot(landscape1000~g120, xlab="Inventory 1, 20m",ylab="Landscape1000m",pch=20)
    model.g120.1km=lm(landscape1000~g120,data=raps)
    abline(model.g120.1km)
    cor.test(g120,landscape1000,method="spearman")
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this is the case?

Comment: you seem to have `landscape1000` and `g120` objects in both your global environment and the `raps` data frame, so make sure they are identical, and update your question with a reproducible example: `plot(mpg ~ wt, mtcars); mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars); abline(mod); with(mtcars, cor.test(wt, mpg, method="spearman"))`

Comment: Thanks a bunch :-)